# Windows 7 SDHC issues

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, sdhc

Windows 7 64-bit is not recognizing a 4GB SDHC card. I can see the drive in Device Manager and it is assigned a drive letter (E:). However the E: drive is not visible in Windows Explorer, nor can I browse to it from a Command Prompt.

Any ideas how to make Windows 7 detect SDHC cards?

Comment: Can you format it in disk manager?

Comment: is your card encrypted with password?

Comment: The card is not encrypted. I can see it in the device manager but cannot perform any operations other than assign a different drive letter.

Comment: Have you tried it on any other PCs? What are you using to read the card?

Comment: Looks like my Alienware card reader cannot read SDHC cards. I returned the card and got a 2gb SD card which, the laptop is happy to read. Thanks everyone. Did try on another winxp laptop. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> My Alienware card reader cannot read SDHC cards. I returned the card
>   and got a 2gb SD card which, the laptop is happy to read.

by [OP](https://superuser.com/questions/90585/windows-7-sdhc-issues#comment92222_90585)